# grey out the div on button click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a form made in jsni. I have added click handler on the button. on click of save button i want the particular div to grey out showing the saving of data.

```
var x=$doc.createElement("div");
x.id="nn";
var lbl=$doc.createElement("Label");
var labelText = $doc.createTextNode("FirstName: ");
lbl.appendChild(labelText);
x.appendChild(lbl);

var a=$doc.createElement("input");
x.appendChild(a);

var br = $doc.createElement("br");
x.appendChild(br);

var lblcl=$doc.createElement("Label");
var labelText1 = $doc.createTextNode(" LastName: ");
lblcl.appendChild(labelText1);
x.appendChild(lblcl);


var b=$doc.createElement ("input");
x.appendChild(b);

var br = $doc.createElement("br");
x.appendChild(br);


var lblc=$doc.createElement("Label");
var labelText2= $doc.createTextNode("CollegeName: ");
lblc.appendChild(labelText2);
x.appendChild(lblc);


var p=$doc.createElement("input");
x.appendChild(p);

var br = $doc.createElement("br");
x.appendChild(br);

var lblcl=$doc.createElement("Label");
var labelText3= $doc.createTextNode(" SchoolName: ");
lblcl.appendChild(labelText3);
x.appendChild(lblcl);


var q=$doc.createElement ("input");
x.appendChild(q);

var yu = $doc.createElement("br");
x.appendChild(yu);

var tr=$doc.createElement("Button");
var buttonTxt = $doc.createTextNode("Save");
tr.appendChild(buttonTxt);
x.appendChild(tr);
body.appendChild(x);
```

I have the following code to grey out but dont know where to place.

```
overlay = document.createElement("div")
overlay.style.width = _width + "px"
overlay.style.height = _height + "px"
overlay.style.position = "absolute"
overlay.style.background = "#dedede"
overlay.style.top = _top + "px"
overlay.style.left = _left + "px"

overlay.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=50)"
overlay.style.opacity = "0.5"
overlay.style.mozOpacity = "0.5"
```

Comment: please paste only relevant bits of your code.

Comment: just to make myself clear i posted the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Create a style that sets the opacity of the div (and therefore its contents). Then all you need to do onclick is append that style to the div.

Comment: its not working the grey out div is been shown below this div but i want the grey effect on the div.

Comment: So append the class to the div you want to grey out - don't use an overlay, just set the opacity of the div you want to grey out by appending a class to do that.

Comment: how can i add external css in jsni

Comment: inn.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;width:100px;height:200px;top=50%;left=100%=px;background:#dedede");

Comment: I'm not sure - here's a quick [search for 'class' at the docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)